# I am fresher for sharepoint i need an document for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I need a documentation for this, e.g. features available, customization, configuration, integration with other software & technologies(java/j2ee), usage, advantages, disadvantages, etc.

Comment: are you fresher for stackoverflow, too? Try the search field and enter "sharepoint documentation" or click on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sharepoint+documentation

Answer (score 2):

[SharePoint Developer Center on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default.aspx)

Plenty to get you started.